# How to move 3 div inside div id="main" to center using css?

Tags: html, css

How do I move the 3 `divs` inside `<div id="main>"` to the center using CSS?

```html
<div id="main" style="float: left;width: 100%;text-align: center;border: 1px solid;">
  <div style="float: left;font-size: 14px;padding: 5px;background: red;">AAA</div>
  <div style="float: left; font-size: 14px; display: block;padding: 5px;background: green;">BBB</div>
  <div style="float: left;font-size: 14px;padding: 5px;background: blue;">CCC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't float the inner divs. Make them `display:inline-block` and set the text-align property on main to center:

```css
#main {
  text-align: center;
}

#main>div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="text-align: center;border: 1px solid;">
  <div style="font-size: 14px;padding: 5px;background: red;">AAA</div><div style="font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;background: green;">BBB</div><div style="font-size: 14px;padding: 5px;background: blue;">CCC</div>
</div>
```

Or using flexbox, try the following (easier):

```css
#main {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="border: 1px solid;">
  <div style="font-size: 14px;padding: 5px;background: red;">AAA</div>
  <div style="font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;background: green;">BBB</div>
  <div style="font-size: 14px;padding: 5px;background: blue;">CCC</div>
</div>
```